# Why is update trigger not triggering?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this trigger, but it is not triggering after an update (the Guid does not get updated).  It is supposed to update the Guid to a new guid if the VendorId changes.  I don't see any issues with it, and I have checked to ensure that it is enabled.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trUpdateGuidAfterVendorChange] on [dbo].[Order]
after update
as
begin
   set nocount on;
   update O set [Guid]=newid()
   from  [Order] O 
   inner join inserted i on O.OrderId=i.OrderId 
   where O.VendorId <> i.VendorId
end
```

Comment: I think you want to join `inserted` on `deleted`, since `order` will have already been updated.

Comment: YOu should post that as an answer @AlwaysLearning , that is almost definately going to be the reason, as `O.VendorId <> i.VendorId` is never going to be TRUE (as the values will always be the same).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, Yes, post as answer and I will accept

Comment: @AlwaysLearning. Please post so I can upvote

Comment: I disagree @Larnu, in his code, he's joining `O.OrderId=i.OrderId`, therefore the VendorId may sometimes be different (if they are different - it will fire). Greg : I would however recommend you check whether the VendorId's are different before updating in the first place, that way, you release a lot more resources... (Just my thoughts)

Comment: @Birel no, it's impossible, as `inserted` contains the values just changed in the `UPDATE` and as the trigger is an **`AFTER INSERT`** then `[Order]` will have those updated values too. If I asked you to remove all the red balls on a bag, and replace them with blue balls, and then **after** find all the red balls in the bag, would you find any?

Comment: Actually, you need to join `Order` with `deleted`...